# Black faces inside transparent object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, faces

I try to render a pointcloud with the object edges shown as reference. Therefor I first created the object and duplicated it. One for the pointcloud and one for the edges as seen in the image below.

Now, most of the points depicted by the gray and red cubes render just fine, but some have a black face. It apears that this happens, if the face of a cube is to close the the face of the object used for rendering the edges.

I set the object blend mode to Alpha Hashed and disabled shadows, but this is still occuring.

How to fix the faces?

[image: Shader and example]

Comment: Please share simplified blend just with the issued Cube ... if the issue is still generated ... Use https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I can not upload the file, due to an error ("There was an internal error attempting to complete your request. "), but here it is: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ajo6x8Lgcmg351UhSNkda4vKXJxn?e=I4C2Kj

Comment: Sorry I forgot ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From provided file, I can't say what cause blacks on the red cube, your file containes only gray cubes ... on top I see several gray cubes in row ...

[image]

The black parts are overlapping two cubes ([z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting)), there are two vertices close to each other.

[image]

So ... just delete upper or lower row of vertices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know, that the example does not contain a red cube, but it should still contain a black face. Never the less, the problem was that the cubes face intersected with the face of the container itself. Scaling up the pointcloud by just 0.001 fixed the problem.